# REGEXP gives different outputs

Tags: sql, regex

I've used REGEXP to find text patterns, but I'm having a problem with one part of it. I'd like to classify a ticketing fare calculation line as having only 1 of the following labels:

1. blank (there are no Q surcharges)
2. QCPN (there are only instance(s) of the existing format Q20.00)
3. QPRO (there are only instance(s) of the new additional format Q LONSYD20.00)
4. QBOTH (there are examples of both QCPN and QBOTH)

Below SQL:

```
SELECT JOUR.JOUR_FSERNR
      AS TICKET,
   CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_LIKE (
                 JOUR.JOUR_FCA1LN
              || JOUR.JOUR_FCA2LN
              || JOUR.JOUR_FCA3LN
              || JOUR.JOUR_FCA4LN,
              'Q[[:space:]][[:alpha:]]{6}')
      THEN
         'QPRO'
      WHEN REGEXP_LIKE (
                 JOUR.JOUR_FCA1LN
              || JOUR.JOUR_FCA2LN
              || JOUR.JOUR_FCA3LN
              || JOUR.JOUR_FCA4LN,
              'Q[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+.*END')
      THEN
         'QCPN'
      WHEN     REGEXP_LIKE (
                     JOUR.JOUR_FCA1LN
                  || JOUR.JOUR_FCA2LN
                  || JOUR.JOUR_FCA3LN
                  || JOUR.JOUR_FCA4LN,
                  'Q[[:space:]][[:alpha:]]{6}')
           AND REGEXP_LIKE (
                     JOUR.JOUR_FCA1LN
                  || JOUR.JOUR_FCA2LN
                  || JOUR.JOUR_FCA3LN
                  || JOUR.JOUR_FCA4LN,
                  '[[ALPHA]]{3}Q[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]')
      THEN
         'QBOTH'
      ELSE
         NULL
   END
      AS QTYPE,
      ( (JOUR.JOUR_FCA1LN || JOUR.JOUR_FCA2LN) || JOUR.JOUR_FCA3LN)
   || JOUR.JOUR_FCA4LN
      AS FARECALC
FROM "S00BJOUR" JOUR
WHERE JOUR.JOUR_FSERNR = '9999889652'
```

If you look at the above SQL and find the CASE WHEN line that outputs 'QCPN', you'll see there's an "END" text string `'Q[[:digit:]][[:graph:]]END'`. I put ‘END’ in there because I only want the REGEXP to look to the left of 'END' in a fare calc line.

But it gives me some incorrect outputs as shown in the attached image [Incorrect Outputs in RED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wLdx.jpg):

Any help to have this corrected is much appreciated.

Comment: Your use of `REGEXP_LIKE` looks totally wrong to me.  Please include sample data and output.

Comment: Hello Tim, refer to the attached image where i have given some examples. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It feels strange, you don't put so much quantifier. Like QCPN, whathever it means shoudld be :

```
Q[[:digit:]]{2}\.[[:digit:]]{2}
```

To match your Q20.00 example at least.

EDIT :

In your "with end exemple", didnt work because you dont put any quantifier :

```
Q[[:digit:]][[:graph:]]END
#Match Q5.END, Q22END, Q8AEND
#Dont match Q20.00 END
```

But :

```
Q[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+.*END
#Match "Q1.2 ZA VD END Q20.2"
#Dont match "Q5.END", "BF END Q10.25"
```

For the second problem, QPRO/QBOTH, the probleme is :

```
Q HAMAOQ20.00
```

Try

```
[[:space:]]Q[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+.
```

For QCPN regex.

Comment: Hello Lavock, many thanks for your response. Adding the quantifier further returns incorrect outputs. QCPN - is when there is only a single Q in the string (eg:AUH EY NYC Q84.17 533.02EOWSTA/GBST NUC617.19END ROE3.672960 XT18.00US3.96XA7.00XY20.42AE9.53F61.36TP1.36ZR). So in this example there is only a single Q of Q84.17.

Comment: QBOTH - is when you have a Q and Q with some characters (eg:BJS EY X/AUH Q100.00EY JNB Q BJSJNB 2.50 267.18NUC369.68END ROE6.507700 XT7.10F61.00ZR) so in this example Q100.00 and Q BJSJNB 2.5

Comment: Your comment is more confusing to me. You say "only one single Q" but you tell us about Q84.17 >.< ?


Your code do exactly what it write, and match only "Q5.END" or so, and you have none.


Btw quantifier only apply to the preceding element. For answering the the second part (something before end), add some .* (like Q[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+.*END).

Comment: Many thanks for your assistance, I have used your inputs but it still gives me an incorrect output for this case "BJS EY X/AUH Q100.00EY JNB Q BJSJNB 2.50 267.18NUC369.68END ROE6.507700 XT7.10F61.00ZR " In this case there is a QCPN which is Q100.00 and QPRO which is Q BJSJNB 2.50, so i expect the output as QBOTH. I have updated the SQL in my original question above.